# Extract data to multiple columns simultaneously in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There is raw data that needs to be **organized with one or two formulas**. I made an example table next to it in the file.

For the first task (yellow cells) you may to use the formula REGEXEXTRACT to extract the data: league, dates, home, away teams and points. From the A:B columns.

For the second task (orange cells), you may also use the REGEXEXTRACT formula to extract the numbers after: zab/2 points, zab/3 points from C:G columns. Since these data are in different cells, you can use this formula:

```
byrow(C3:G;lambda(Σ;if(counta(Σ)=0;;ifna(--regexextract(torow(index(if(regexmatch(Σ;O2);Σ;);1);"(\d+):")))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added couple of formulas [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/120uFhs7DwWVvC3_fPmFn5HefkuT1JNOk_dCV2ZPBrxI/edit#gid=1494935165):

***League formula***:

```
=map(A3:A;B3:B;lambda(Σ;Δ;if(Σ="";;{regexextract(Σ;"\. (.*)")\regexextract(Δ;"(.*) at")\regexextract(Δ;"\d([a-zA-Z].*) –")\regexextract(Δ;"– (.*)")})))
```

***Points Formula***:

```
=byrow($B3:$G;lambda(Σ;if(counta(Σ)=0;;index(
      let(Δ;ifna(regexextract(torow(if(regexmatch(Σ;O1);Σ;);1);"(\d+):(\d+) \((\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)-(\d+)(?: (\d+)-(\d+))?\)\n"));
       if(len(Δ);--Δ;))))))
```

[image]